# ansible template use variable and string

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to fill an ansible variable with:

- "docker-ce" if on RedHat
- "docker" otherwise

the following works, but is not very clean:

```
docker_edition: 'ce'
docker_package: docker{{ "-" if (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") else "" }}{{ docker_edition if (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") else "" }}
```

I would like to write this in a single ternary expression, I have tried the following:

```
docker_package: "docker{{ (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") | ternary("","-{{ docker_edition }}") }}"
docker_package: docker{{ (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") | ternary("","-{{ docker_edition }}") }}
docker_package: docker{{ -{{ docker_edition }} if (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") else "" }}
```

but I fail to get this working.

For clarification, the following would work:

```
{{ "docker-ce" if (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") else "docker" }}
```

but I want to keep the `docker_edition` variable separate since it is used elsewhere.

Comment: You "fail to get it working" ... because? It produces an error message? If so, what error? As for combining the ternary, isn't `docker_package: docker{{ ("-" + docker_edition) if ansible_os_family == "RedHat" else "" }}` what you're after?

Comment: @mdaniel: It seems that, when posting the question, I accidentally posted the answer (without knowing). I edited my question to show all possible combinations I tried before.

Answer (score 0):

the following works:

```
docker_package: docker{{ "-" + docker_edition if (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") else "" }}
```